# Does WCF require a separate hosting

Tags: asp.net, wcf, dynamic-data, asp.net-4.0

I am using WCF with asp.net 4.0 (using Dynamic Data).
I need to tell my Client how many domains does he require to book. So, do i require a separate domain/sub-domain for WCF or just 1 domain for website and WCF would work. 
FYI: We might acquire a hosting space at shared hosting servers like GoDaddy.com. I need to calculate the hosting cost of the application.

Thanks

Comment: it depends on the service and how you use it... technically all can live together on the same domain just fine... for a security POV there could some other things to take into account...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host WCF in IIS, or you can host it in a separate program/service. If you're hosting it in IIS, you can create a `.svc` file and have it live alongside your other ASP.NET pages.

So it's entirely possible to have your WCF service live in the same domain as your ASP.NET app.

Comment: I'll just add that instead of a entirely separate domain or hosting outside of IIS, you could also use sub domains if you find that your WCF services need to be separate for one reason or another.

Comment: @Randolpho: I think hosting it on sub-domain will have some cost. So, i would probably go with a folder and .svc file inside it. Thanks for quick answer.

Comment: @Jason: I know sub-domain thing and its benefits. But, the site is very small, and client can't afford unnecessary cost. And sub-domain will have extra cost. But, thanks for the efforts.